# NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType serial or concurrent?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

As the title says, the question is, if a `NSManagedObjectContext` with concurrency type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` is serial or concurrent.

More specifically, if I call

```
[managedObjectContext performBlock:^{

}];
```

with a long running task, will other calls to that context with performBlock be blocked until the first one finished?

Answer (score 4):

It is serial queue from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1).

Or you can simply try to run this code and see the result. The numbers will be printed serially.

```
    let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateMOC.perform {
        for i in 0...8000 {
            if i.isMultiple(of: 3000) {
                print("1")
            }
        }
    }
    privateMOC.perform {
        for i in 0...8000 {
            if i.isMultiple(of: 3000) {
                print("2")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it's documented either way. However, Core Data is generally not thread-safe, and the `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` methods are ways of dealing with that-- by putting all of your Core Data work on a single queue. As such I'd be extremely surprised if it was a concurrent queue, since the whole point is to avoid concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find any evidence in the official docs but recently I worked with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and I remember it was serial. Also [this blog post](http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/97430076027/a-real-guide-to-core-data-concurrency) states that:

> When an NSManagedObjectContext is created with the initializer initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] or -[initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType] all access to the context and it’s managed objects must go through the method -[performBlock: or -[performBlockAndWait:] . Core Data is using a serial queue to ensure that operations on the context are performed in order, and that only one operation is happening at a time

Answer (score 2):

It's a serial queue. You code will be performed serially when you call `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` if you specify `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

Apple doesn't pick the word `PrivateQueue` randomly, `Private Queue` = `Serial Queue` in Apple's documents. See here for the [Serial Queue description](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1)

> Serial queues (also known as private dispatch queues) execute one task at a time in the order in which they are added to the queue.

Also, I have double checked that in debugging. Please see the last thread in the below screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` uses the main queue. The main queue is bound to the main thread and therefore serial.

> The main dispatch queue is a globally available serial queue that executes tasks on the application’s main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested that all tasks will be **executed in sequence**, but It may be **executed in a different thread**

```
 backgroundContext.perform {
    print("perform------:\(self.number)", Thread.current)
    self.number += 1
 }
```

[image]